# Use of properties in java

Tags: java, properties

I'm new here and i would like to ask on how `properties` can work with the java codes i mean the `values` inside of the `properties` will be use as variables. For example i have `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` inside  `config.properties` and store it in an `Arraylist` then scan the folder and if the files are found copy it. My work only shows the names of the data from the properties that is stored in the arraylist but my another problem is how these data will be copied to another folder.

so far this is my code

```
     public class MainClass {

          static Properties prop = new Properties();
    static InputStream input = null;
    static String filename = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File source = new File("D:/ojt");
        File dest = new File("D:/ojt/New folder");


        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;


        try {

    //    getFiles(filename);


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
       private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;

            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(source);
                os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
                os.close();
            }
        }
       private static void copy(String fromPath, String outputPath)
       {
    //       filter = new FileTypeOrFolderFilter(fileType);
           File currentFolder = new File(fromPath);
           File outputFolder = new File(outputPath);
           scanFolder(currentFolder, outputFolder);


       }

      private static void getFiles(String path) throws IOException{
        //Put filenames in arraylist<string>
        String filename = "bydatefilesdir.props";
        input = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
        File dir = new File(path);
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            list.add(s.nextLine());
        }
//      ArrayList<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
//      for(File file : dir.listFiles()){
//          filenames.add(file.getName());
//      }

        prop.load(input);
        //Check if the files are in the arraylist
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            String s1 = list.get(i);
            System.out.println("File "+i+" : "+s1);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(source);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
    }
    private static void copy(String source, String dest)
    {
        //       filter = new FileTypeOrFolderFilter(fileType);
        File currentFolder = new File(source);
        File outputFolder = new File(dest);
        scanFolder(currentFolder, outputFolder);


    }

    private static void scanFolder(File source, File dest)
    {
        System.out.println("Scanning folder [" + source.toString() + "]...\n");
        File[] files = source.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                scanFolder(source, dest);
            } else {
                try {
                    copyFileUsingStream(source, dest);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: sorry for the poor programming just new in java.. still learning
Edited: I've included the updated codes above..

Comment: If you just want a file containing a list of files, you shouldn’t use Properties.  Just read the file line by line using a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Comment: the values that inside of the properties are filenames only, so if I run the program it will scan the folder and if the filename from the properties equals to the filename in that folder it will be copied.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose java.util.Properties has build in methods to achieve what you are trying.
please refer this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) and you will find a better solution.

```
public class App {

  public static void main( String[] args ){

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        String filename = "config.properties";
        input = App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
        if(input==null){
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
            return;
        }

        //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
        prop.load(input);

            //get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("file1.txt"));
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("file2.txt"));


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(input!=null){
            try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: how can you store it on a `arraylist`?